# Закрывается приложение вне среды разработки C#

Tags: c#

Как можно отловить причину закрытия Windows Form вне среды Visual Studio ? И Debug и Release идентично закрываются..есть какое нибудь логирование для этого случая ?

Comment: отловил ошибку
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MetroFramework, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f91a84759bf584a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."

Как решить ? Ссылки в проекте есть..в VS собирается и открывается

Comment: попробуй переустановить MetroFramework. мне помогало

Comment: Переустановил..0 эмоций. Использую MetroModernUI..все равно закрывается по той же причине

Comment: В папке bin/debug эти сборки есть? Если нет, то кликаем в студии в references на сборку правой кнопкой мыши, выбираем copy to output

Comment: Я извиняюсь..но такого пункта нет..в bin/debug все есть..и файлы типа локали и тот самый MetroFramework.dll

Comment: `либо одну из их зависимостей` зависимости в bin/debug есть? Версии совпадают?

Comment: Все совпадает...не запускается и все

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать установить nuget пакет с соответствующей библиотекой и тогда должно точно подтянуться в проект библиотека и все её зависимости. Ещё можно попробовать запустить exe от администратора.

Comment: Запускаю от админа..даже манифест указал, что нужен админ..галочку в безопасности снял..ему вообще насрать..без MetroFramework все хорошо работает.. А как понять..какой именно пакет..вроде метро установил и у него нет зависимостей подписано

Comment: Можно как-то в студии, но также можно через dotPeek. Он сразу показывает на что у библиотеки есть референсы.

Answer (score 0):

В общем помогло прямое копирование всех DLL MetroFramework'a в ту же папку, где лежит .exe файл..Почему то они там не появлялись. Только сам MetroFramework.dll. Уверен, что это не решение, а **костыль** )

Comment: Можно написать в событиях после построения, чтобы библиотека копировалась в выходной каталог (bin\Release). Посмотри статью: 
https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2014/02/using-build-events-in-visual-studio-to.html

Comment: Библиотека отображается в референсах проекта? Тогда можно зайти в Properties/Copy Local поставить в True